# tiling on a roll wallpaper

Tags: tile

hi I am thinking of using tiling on a roll wallpaper on to my kitchen tiles as I don't like them but I am not allowed to remove them. What type of glue do I need to use please ?

Comment: "using tiling on a roll wallpaper on to my kitchen tiles"  **What does that mean ?** tiling on a roll wallpaper, what is it, wallpaper ?  Please be more detailed with your explanation so we can help.

Comment: yes it is wallpaper for the kitchen so Its thicker and waterproof but I need to know what glue to use as I am sticking on the my tiles and not onto a wall.

Comment: Common question here. You say you are not allowed to remove the existing tiles. Is that rule set by a landlord or rental agreement? If so there may be similar restrictions about trying to stick something over the tiles in a semi permanent manner.

Comment: Not that I landlord, but if I *were* a landlord, and had put in ceramic tiles, it would be "kiss your security deposit goodbye" at a minimum if I found them covered with imitation tiling. If you rent, and don't like the tiles, and cannot come to an agreement with your landlord about changing the tiles, then start looking for a new place to rent...

Comment: I live in social housing as long as I can get it off I will be ok

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting to do (if I understand it correctly) is to put some sort of wallpaper on the tile backsplash of your kitchen. That is not something that anyone does... so there will be no glue made to do it. You are likely on your own here, meaning you will have to experiment. You will need something relatively waterproof if it's near the sink / faucet, but also you will need something that will come off of the tile easily when you move out, because your landlord is NOT going to take kindly to you leaving it for them.

You MIGHT try sray-on carpet glue, sprayed onto the back of the WALLPAPER, not sprayed on the tile. But I would try a small patch in an inconspicuous area first, see if it holds, then see if it comes off again, especially after a few days or maybe even weeks, before committing to the bigger project. You could also do the same with standard wallpaper paste, it MIGHT hold onto the tile, but it would have to be SQUEAKY clean first, no oily residues.

Good luck!